# Using for as topicalizer in given / when as expression (return value) does not work

Tags: perl, syntax, switch-statement

I've tried to use [Perl's given / when construct as expression](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Return-value) in subroutine which should return a string containing some warning under some circumstances or an empty string otherwise:

```
sub warn_about_invalid_date {
    my ( $date ) = @_;
    return do {
        given ($date) { # <------------ works only with given, does not with for
            when (not /^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}$/) {
                'Invalid date format (should be YYYY-MM-DD)';
            }
            when ('0001-01-01') {
                'Use of default date "0001-01-01"';
            }
            when ($_ lt '1900-01-01') {
                'Probably too far in the past (year < 1900)';
            }
            when ($_ gt '2100-01-01') {
                'Probably too far in the future (year > 2100)';
            }
            default {
                '';
            }
        }
    };
}
```

*(Please ignore some redundant / verbose / non-idiomatic Perl code like `return do { }` or semicolons at the end of each expression, these are coding practices in my company.)*

However, because I try to follow Perl good practices, also these from brian d foy's [Effective Perl](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321496949), here [Use for() instead of given()](http://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/2011/05/use-for-instead-of-given/), I've swapped `given` with `for` in the snippet above and... it didn't work as I expected. Return value for any input was always `''` (empty string / false).

I've narrowed down the problem to this case:

```
use v5.10.1;
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

sub test_for {
    for (shift) {
        when (1) { 'True' }
        default  { 'False' }
    }
}

sub test_given {
    given (shift) {
        when (1) { 'True' }
        default  { 'False' }
    }
}

sub test_if {
    if (shift) { 'True' }
    else  { 'False' }
}

sub test_given_if {
    given (shift) {
        if ($_) { 'True' }
        else  { 'False' }
    }
}

sub test_for_if {
    for (shift) {
        if ($_) { 'True' }
        else  { 'False' }
    }
}

$Data::Dumper::Indent = 0;
$Data::Dumper::Terse = 1;
say "test_for( $_ ): ", Dumper test_for($_) for 0..1;
say "test_given( $_ ): ", Dumper test_given($_) for 0..1;
say "test_if( $_ ): ", Dumper test_if($_) for 0..1;
say "test_for_if( $_ ): ", Dumper test_for_if($_) for 0..1;
say "test_given_if( $_ ): ", Dumper test_given_if($_) for 0..1;
```

which outputs

```
perl-5.10.1
==========
Useless use of a constant in void context at /home/grozn/test3a.pl line 9.
Useless use of a constant in void context at /home/grozn/test3a.pl line 16.
Useless use of a constant in void context at /home/grozn/test3a.pl line 35.
Useless use of a constant in void context at /home/grozn/test3a.pl line 36.
Useless use of a constant in void context at /home/grozn/test3a.pl line 42.
test_for( 0 ): ''
test_for( 1 ): ''
test_given( 0 ): 
test_given( 1 ): 
test_if( 0 ): 'False'
test_if( 1 ): 'True'
test_for_if( 0 ): ''
test_for_if( 1 ): ''
test_given_if( 0 ): 
test_given_if( 1 ): 
test_for_constant( 0 ): ''
test_for_constant( 1 ): ''


perl-5.16
==========
Useless use of a constant ("True") in void context at /home/grozn/test3a.pl line 35.
Useless use of a constant ("False") in void context at /home/grozn/test3a.pl line 36.
Useless use of a constant ("Foo") in void context at /home/grozn/test3a.pl line 42.
test_for( 0 ): ''
test_for( 1 ): ''
test_given( 0 ): 'False'
test_given( 1 ): 'True'
test_if( 0 ): 'False'
test_if( 1 ): 'True'
test_for_if( 0 ): ''
test_for_if( 1 ): ''
test_given_if( 0 ): 'False'
test_given_if( 1 ): 'True'
test_for_constant( 0 ): ''
test_for_constant( 1 ): ''


perl-5.18
==========
when is experimental at /home/grozn/test3a.pl line 9.
given is experimental at /home/grozn/test3a.pl line 15.
when is experimental at /home/grozn/test3a.pl line 16.
given is experimental at /home/grozn/test3a.pl line 27.
Useless use of a constant ("True") in void context at /home/grozn/test3a.pl line 35.
Useless use of a constant ("False") in void context at /home/grozn/test3a.pl line 36.
Useless use of a constant ("Foo") in void context at /home/grozn/test3a.pl line 42.
test_for( 0 ): ''
test_for( 1 ): ''
test_given( 0 ): 'False'
test_given( 1 ): 'True'
test_if( 0 ): 'False'
test_if( 1 ): 'True'
test_for_if( 0 ): ''
test_for_if( 1 ): ''
test_given_if( 0 ): 'False'
test_given_if( 1 ): 'True'
test_for_constant( 0 ): ''
test_for_constant( 1 ): ''
```

*(warning points to `test_for_if`)*
when executed from perls 5.10.1, 5.16.3 and 5.18.1.

**My question is:**

Is that correct behavior of `for` / `when` expression? It's not implicitely documented as such ([Given / when's "Return value" subsection is in "Experimental Details on given and when" section](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Return-value) and mentions given only) but from what I understood `for` is a proper replacement for `given` (`for` should be as good topicalizer as `given` here, shouldn't it?).

If this is a correct behavior then is there any reason to use `for` instead of `given` in Perl 5.18 which [fixes how `given` treats `$_`](https://metacpan.org/module/RJBS/perl-5.18.0/pod/perldelta.pod#given-now-aliases-the-global-_)? Or should I fill a bug / send a pull request in Perl's documentation?

If it's broken, should I fill a bug in Perl (I mean should I always treat `for` as `given` more comprehensive twin brother)?

**EDIT:**

I've added three cases with an `if` after [choroba's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18339162/708434) and comment in which he clams that *`for` behaves the same way as `if` and company*. And I've got even more confused after that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the missing `return`s to the `test_for` subroutine to get the same behaviour. `given` returns the value of the last expression evaluated, `for` does not.

Comment: Shouldn't `for` behave just like `given`? I mean is there any reason not to add to `for` this behavior?

Comment: `for` behaves the same way as `if` and company. The return value of `given` is docummented. If you think it should be otherwise, you can try to file a bugreport.

Comment: Please see edited question, `for` does not behave exactly the same way as `if`, using `if` gives me a warning. Maybe that's the way `for` should behave here? I think that  parser / compiler should be able to tell that use of constants is useless in `test_for`, too.

Comment: @Xaerxess: It behaves the same if you supply a constant to `for`. You supplied `when`.

Comment: I see... But shouldn't the compiler be able to warn about useless use of constant in `when` statement which is inside `for` which ignores constants in last expression? I feel like this inconsistency (comparing to `given` / `when`, not to `if`) should be marked somehow.

Comment: @Xaerxess: in perl 5.18, `when` is considered an experimental feature and Perl warns about it. This is part of why.